# iptables Forward port range on dd-wrt for proxmox vnc

Tags: iptables, dd-wrt, proxmox

I am running proxmox on my LAN and DD-WRT for my router... I want to use cloudflare with proxmox, but cloud flare only allows these ports(https): 2087, 2096, 8443. But proxmox VNC ports are 5900-5999..chosen at random.

How can I set an iptables rule in dd-wrt to forward any outbound traffic from 192.168.1.250:5900-5999 to WANIP:2087, 2096, 8443?